Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.sepolia.url - Expected a value of type string
the code is
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 **/
require ("dotenv").config();
require ("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.7",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    sepolia: {
      url: API_URL,
      account: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};

It shows error while running this "npx hardhat compile"

It seems like you haven't defined the API_URL environment variable in your .env file.
As, you're using these two environment variables in your hardhat.config.js file:
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

So, there must be a .env file in your root folder of the project containing these two variables, like:
API_URL="SEPOLIA_RPC_URL"
PRIVATE_KEY="YOUR_TEST_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY"

NOTE:

You can get the private Sepolia RPC URL using RPC providers like Alchemy, Infura, etc. Or, you can get the public one from Chainlist.

You can export your test account private key from your MetaMask by following this article.


